# Reading tabular txt file in python

Tags: python, text

I have .txt file that contains tabular data in the following form:

```
3   EA1603S 14/01/2014  2443.60 27.42   249579  673473  200 2   0   2100-2200   16032   2   16032
3   EA1603V 14/01/2014  2443.60 27.42   1000    673473  10  1   0   2100-2200   16035   5   16035
3   EA1603W 14/01/2014  2443.60 27.42   349579  673473  200 2   0   2100-2200   16036   6   16036
```

I want to be able to read (and, if possible, also edit) this file with python. for example, I want to be able to specify row 1, column 5 and to get the value 1000. What is the easiest way to do it in Python, preferably without using additional packages? It's possible to convert the file to other formats, if needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
In [331]:

import pandas as pd
import io
t="""3   EA1603S 14/01/2014  2443.60 27.42   249579  673473  200 2   0   2100-2200   16032   2   16032
3   EA1603V 14/01/2014  2443.60 27.42   1000    673473  10  1   0   2100-2200   16035   5   16035
3   EA1603W 14/01/2014  2443.60 27.42   349579  673473  200 2   0   2100-2200   16036   6   16036"""
​
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep='\s+', header=None)
df.iloc[1][5]
Out[331]:
1000
```

Pandas uses [DataFrames](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) primarily that is well suited to your data structure, it supports updating, insertion, fast lookup and filtering, your df looks like this after loading:

```
In [332]:

df
Out[332]:
   0        1           2       3      4       5       6    7   8   9   \
0   3  EA1603S  14/01/2014  2443.6  27.42  249579  673473  200   2   0   
1   3  EA1603V  14/01/2014  2443.6  27.42    1000  673473   10   1   0   
2   3  EA1603W  14/01/2014  2443.6  27.42  349579  673473  200   2   0   

          10     11  12     13  
0  2100-2200  16032   2  16032  
1  2100-2200  16035   5  16035  
2  2100-2200  16036   6  16036
```

Although you mention without using additional packages I IMO this is the easiest and most suited library for this type of data analysis, it also supports outputting to various other [formats](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#input-output)

Comment: Thank you, is it also possible to do this without additional libraries?

Comment: All things are possible, the question is do you want to cruft custom code to read this file once or just install an existing package that is flexible enough to handle most structured text data?

Comment: The thing is that I'm a total begginer, and I want to use it in Kivy in order to develop an android app, and from my previous dismal experience, whenever I try to combine different libraries and packages I get "no module named..." errors that I don't manage to solve despite of my efforts...